# Django admin restrict access to list view

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Here is a model:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    identity_number= models.IntegerField(unique=True)
```

`name` field should be public, `identity_number`, however, should be confidential.

I would like to show `name` in admin list view and both fields in change form view.

I would like to create one group of users, who can access only list view and another group of users, who can access both views.

This means that the first group of users should not see links to change form and if they try to access the change form page directly, `403` (or something like that) should be returned. How to achieve this?

Comment: Create a new group and add user to that group with permission read Person. You can do it easily by django admin.

Comment: Using Django 2.1.3 I do not see `read` permission. The options are `add`, `view`, `change` and `delete`.
The `view` permission is not what I am looking for since it provides read-only access to change form as well, not only to list view.

Comment: By saying `list view` you mean `django.views.generic.list.ListView` or `change_list` ?

Comment: I mean `change_list`, sorry about messing up the terminology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by `list view` you mean the `changelist_view` then you can do:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'identity_number', )

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        if request.user.groups.filter(name='your_group_name').exists():
            self.list_display = ('name', )
            # if you dont want any links to the change_form
            self.list_display_links = None
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)
```